# A difficult differential equation $ y(2x^4+y)\frac{dy}{dx} = (1-4xy^2)x^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation?
$$ y(2x^4+y)\dfrac{dy}{dx} = (1-4xy^2)x^2$$

No clue as to how to even begin. Hints?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: it's an exact differential equation.

Comment: Please drop some more hint. This doesn't seem so straight forward to me.

Comment: Well, I am familiar, but that's just it. I am only familiar. I haven't mastered it yet. I tried to bring it in an exact form, but I couldn't.

Comment: Wait, I think there's some terminology issue here. By *Exact method*, do you mean writing the equation so that it is expressed as $ d( \text{blob} ) = \text{something integrable}$? I just googled the 'exact' method and what I got was something with partial derivatives. That, I do not know.

Comment: You are writing $M dx + N dy = 0$: see http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Exact.aspx for worked examples. Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot for that resource. Just began reading and seems nice! +1!

Comment: You might also try http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/exact/exact.html

Answer (score 5):

$$y(2x^4+y)\frac{dy}{dx}=(1-4xy^2)x^2$$

$$2x^4y\frac{dy}{dx}+y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2-4x^3 y^2$$

$$2x^4y\frac{dy}{dx}+4x^3y^2+y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^4 y^2)+y^2\frac{dy}{dx}=x^2$$

$$x^4y^2+\frac{y^3}{3}=\frac{x^3}{3}+C$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
Apply $M(x,y)=\frac{du}{dx}$   and    $ N(x,y)=\frac{du}{dy}$

Answer (score -1):

Since this is an exact differential equation, it is written in the form $N(x, y)+y'M(x, y)=0$ Rewriting the equation, we get$$(4x^3y^2-1)+\frac{dy}{dx}(2x^4y+y^2)=0$$From here, we can see clearly that $N(x, y)=4x^3y^2-1$ and $M(x, y)=2x^4y+y^2$. Now let $\Psi_x=N$ and $\Psi_y=M$. Therefore, $$\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$Recall that this is similar to the multivariable chain rule: $$\frac{d\Psi(x, y(x))}{dx}=\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{dx}{dx}+\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial\Psi}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$This means that $\Psi$ is the solution to the differential equation. $$\Psi=\int\Psi_x\;dx=\int N\;dx\;\;OR\;\;\int\Psi_y\;dy=\int M\;dy$$
$$\int N\;dx=\int4x^3y^2-1\;dx=x^4y^2-x+h(y)+C_1$$$$\int M\;dx=\int2x^4y+y^2\;dy=x^4y^2+\frac{1}{3}y^3+g(x)+C_2$$
Combining, we get$$\Psi=x^4y^2-x+\frac{1}{3}y^3+C$$ Because the derivative of $\Psi$ is $0$, $\Psi$ must evaluate to a constant $$\boxed{x^4y^2-x+\frac{1}{3}y^3=C}$$

Comment: I think you have made a mistake. Please double-check.